# Unable to call through https request

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I'm using the website which contain .svc file and hosted on https as rest api. My question is:
My website has `SVCUTIL.exe` is `https://XXXXXXX` but when I call it with https request it fails but working fine with http request.And I don’t want  use SSL certificates
Thanks

This is my webconfig settings:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Mybehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Mybehaviour" name="PBUIService">
    <endpoint address="https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" behaviorConfiguration="PBBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingSettings" contract="PBUIService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding"
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>   
</services>
```

Comment: You could enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your WCF service to see what is happening when using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following lines to make it work with https:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>           
    </bindings>
```

Comment: You are right but in this case i have to use SSL certificate on client side but that i dont want because I treat this as a web api.

Comment: <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingSettings" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
     
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>